# ASP.NET error: "Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed"

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a huge problem with this method im trying to make. I have a web page where i need to write a method that returns the editor for a specific property. The method for the color implements the "JQUERY Colorpicker from eyecon.ro".

```
private static string GetColorBox(string name, int width, string value)
{
    return "<input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"6\" size=\"6\" id=\"colorPickerHolder" + name + "\" value=\"000000\" />" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
        "$('#colorPickerHolder" + name + "').ColorPicker(" +
        "{" +
          "onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) " +
          "{" +
            "$(el).val(hex);" +
            "$(el).ColorPickerHide();" +
          "}," +
          "onBeforeShow: function () " +
          "{" +
            "$(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);" +
          "}" +
        "})" +
        ".bind('keyup', function()" +
        "{" +
          "$(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);" +
        "});" +
    "</script>";
}
```

I have several calls to this method but after the first invocation the second one complains that:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; GTB6; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR
>   3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Mon, 9 Nov 2009 19:35:33 UTC
>
> Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container
>   element before the child element is closed (KB927917) Line: 0 Char: 0
>   Code: 0 URI: http://localhost:1442/Slide/CreateTemplateSlide/33

The HTML it renders appears like this:

```
<tr>
    <td width="150px" nowrap="nowrap">
        Text color:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorPickerHolderTextColor" value="000000" /><script type="text/javascript">$('#colorPickerHolderTextColor').ColorPicker({onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {$(el).val(hex);$(el).ColorPickerHide();},onBeforeShow: function () {$(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);}}).bind('keyup', function(){$(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);});</script>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="150px" nowrap="nowrap">
        Text size:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="TextSize" width="5px" type="text" value=""></input>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="150px" nowrap="nowrap">
        Background color:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorPickerHolderBackColor" value="000000" ><script type="text/javascript">$('#colorPickerHolderBackColor').ColorPicker({onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {$(el).val(hex);$(el).ColorPickerHide();},onBeforeShow: function () {$(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);}}).bind('keyup', function(){$(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);});</script>
    </td>
```

I have no clue what so ever about why this is happening, anyone pls point me in the right direction?

Comment: Edited the above, closed the input tag, tried this without any luck, still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the `input` tag before the `script` tag.

**EDIT**: You may also want to remove the script part from that call and make a dedicated one that will work on a particular class.

```
private static string GetColorBox(string name, int width, string value)
{
    return "<input class=\"myParticularColorBoxingClass\" type=\"text\" maxlength=\"6\" size=\"6\" id=\"colorPickerHolder" + name + "\" value=\"000000\" >";
}
```

**EDIT2**: You can run the script only once, by directly adding it in the page.
Please can you try putting this inside your page?
Remember to add `class=\"myParticularColorBoxingClass\"`  (see above method).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //run this after document has finished loading!
    $(document).ready(
      function() { 
         //activate all inputs with "myParticularColorBoxingClass" class
         $('input .myParticularColorBoxingClass').ColorPicker(
                {
                  onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el)
                  {
                    $(el).val(hex);
                    $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                  },
                  onBeforeShow: function () 
                  {
                    $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                  }
                })
                .bind('keyup', function()
                {
                  $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                });
      }
   );
</script>
```

Comment: And i should then call two methods? what are the purpose of splitting the calls into two seperate calls?

Tried closing the input tag, still no luck...modified the code in the original post to reflect this

Comment: Wuhuuu it works now, thx a bunch for helping out, u just saved my day/night :-)